# how to add the value of a cell from an excel sheet into another excel sheet depending on the value from a 3rd sheet

Tags: vba, excel

i have a task to complete in excel which uses 3 excel sheets. My task it to use the value of a cell in sheet 1 to to look up the same value in sheet 2 and add the value of the cell adjacent to it into sheet 3. For example, sheet 1 cell A2 = billy.  sheet 2 cell B4 = billy and sheet 2 cell A4 =1234 so sheet 3 cell A2 should = 1234. any help on this matter is much appreciated

i have tried this format and it gives me #N/A and #REF

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A2,Sheet3!A:B,Sheet3!A2,FALSE)
```

where sheet1 A2 is billy and sheet3 A:B is the sheet im searching for matching values and sheet3 A2 is the 1234 i want into my cell
im not sure if i have the syntax right

Many thanks

Billy

Comment: has been asked many times... do your research or demonstrate what you have tried, what didnt work then maybe someone will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the VLookup can be a problem, if your return values are in the rightmost column of the search array. The formula 
        `=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,1,FALSE)` would work, if you were searching for billy in sheet2, column A, and returning column B-values instead of the other way around. Try using INDEX-MATCH syntax for this scenario instead:
`=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!B:B,0))`
Otherwise have a look at the VLOOKUP-OFFSET combo. You might find these references useful:
[Say goodbye to Vlookup](http://thinketg.com/say-goodbye-to-vlookup-and-hello-to-index-match/), [Dynamics searching using VLOOKUP, MATCH and INDEX](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dynamic-searching-using-vlookup-match-and-index-HA001154902.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check vlookup functions in excel, this function looks for a given value in the given table's first column and gives you the found value with an row offset (in this case the value A4 =1234 you are looking for). you can learn the usage from excel help.